# Add new row at bottom of datagridview in Winform

Tags: c#, .net, winforms

I have a datagridview in Winform application. When I click on add button I want a blank row to be inserted at the bottom of datagridview.

I tried this one:

```
dataGridView1.Rows.Add(row);
```

But blank row is inserted at top not at the bottom. Is there any way to insert it at the bottom?

Comment: What is `row`? an empty `DataGridViewRow`?

Comment: Better way might be, adding an instance of your Model to your GridView's DataSource... Being a new instance, it should display a row with default values (Which if strings, should be empty)

Comment: Yes row is an empty DataGridViewRow.

Comment: @Priyanka try `dataGridView1.Rows.Add(1);`, it's strange that the new row is added at the top, unless you have some data in the row and some `Sorting` is currently applied, it may change the row order.

Comment: Instead of acting on the View, I am recommending to change the ViewModel (object being binded to the View).

Comment: My datagridview already contains some rows with data.If i add this line dataGridView1.Rows.Add(1); it will every time get added at first location.I want it to be added at the bottom.

Comment: `dataGridView1.Rows.Add(row)` returns an integer check that and let me know what it returns

Comment: dataGridView1.Rows.Add(row) returns 1.

Answer (score 3):

you can use `Insert` method:

```
dataGridView1.Rows.Insert(dataGridView1.Rows.Count-1, row);
```