# adding new row to the bottom of datagridview

Tags: c#, datagridview

I have datagridview with one column and one record on my form and I want to add new row to the bottom of datagridview with the click of a button and populate the last cell with `Rows.Count` number. but it seems that when the new row is added with `dataGridView1.Rows.Add()` method, it is inserted to the top of current row. How can I Insert a row to the bottom of datagridview? Is this behavior expected?

Thanks.

```
private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
 {

    dataGridView1.Rows[dataGridView1.Rows.Count-1].Cells[0].Value = dataGridView1.Rows.Count;
    dataGridView1.Rows.Add();

}
```

[image]

Comment: Duplicate --> http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18440668/add-new-row-at-bottom-of-datagridview-in-winform

Comment: I just used `dataGridView1.Rows.Insert(dataGridView1.Rows.Count - 1, 1)` but the row is added to top. Please correct me if I'm wrong?

Comment: Which technology are you using? WPF, Windows Forms? Is the datagrid bound to something?

Comment: it is simple Windows form. datagrid is not bound to.

Comment: I just tried your code (Without the `dataGridView1.Rows.Add.Add()`) and mine is inserted at the bottom.  Probably your DataGridView is sorted by some column.

Comment: @Pabinator What do you mean without `dataGridView1.Rows.Add()` Did you use `Insert` method?

Comment: I just used the `dataGridView1.Rows[dataGridView1.Rows.Count-1].Cells[0].Value = dataGridView1.Rows.Count;`.  Now, the image that you just inserted shows it at the bottom so now I don't understand what do you mean by "I want to add new row to the bottom of datagridview"?

Comment: @Pabinator Initially there is only one row let's say we want its value to be 1, I want to insert another row to the bottom of first row and make its value 2. you cannot have new rows with `dataGridView1.Rows[dataGridView1.Rows.Count-1].Cells[0].Value = dataGridView1.Rows.Count` without first adding it. Image shows number 2 at third row because the row is Inserted to the top

Answer (score 2):

Though the question may be a [duplicate](https://stackoverflow.com/q/18440668/3773066), the answer provided on that question is not a sufficient solution. You'll see why.

You are operating under the idea that `dataGridView1.Rows.Add();` is adding a new row at "*the top of [the] current row.*" This isn't quite the case. With your current setup, the following is defaulted in the designer:

```
this.dataGridView1.AllowUserToAddRows = true;
```

This results in the bottom (uncommited) row of the grid, indicated by the * symbol. This is the *NewRow*, as indicated in code by accessing with `this.dataGridView1.NewRowIndex`. Any time you edit this row, it is commited and another *NewRow* is added.

[image: DGV NewRow]

Why does that matter? Because when you have this property set to `true`, calling `dataGridView1.Rows.Add()` adds a new row to the bottom of your *commited* rows, before the NewRow. For example:

```
private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    dataGridView1.Rows[dataGridView1.Rows.Count-1].Cells[0].Value = dataGridView1.Rows.Count;
    dataGridView1.Rows.Add(new object[] { "I'm new" });   
}
```

[image: Added Row]

The proposed answer: `dataGridView1.Rows.Insert(dataGridView1.Rows.Count - 1, 1)` will do the exact same thing. Hence why it isn't a solution.

**Solution**

Swap the order of your two lines of code.

```
private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    dataGridView1.Rows.Add();
    dataGridView1.Rows[dataGridView1.Rows.Count-1].Cells[0].Value = dataGridView1.Rows.Count;   
}
```

[image: solved]

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    object[] rowData = new object[dataGridView1.Columns.Count];
    rowData[0] = dataGridView1.Rows.Count;
    dataGridView1.Rows.Add(rowData);          
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Write Code in Row Add button click event like below

```
private void btnRowAdd_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    String[] row = { "", "", "", "", "", "", "" };
    dataGridView1.Rows.Add(row);
    dataGridView1.AllowUserToAddRows = false;
}
```

Here is row add button:
[image: Here is row add button]

Then also called that event in new button like below:

[image: Here is new button]

```
btnRowAdd_Click(e, e);
```

Answer (score 0):

I found the answer. I call this method to add a new row at the bottom of my DataGridView.

this.dataGridView1.NotifyCurrentCellDirty(true);

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/LOrsK.jpg)

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow. Please clarify your question. See [ask].